# JavaScript keyup eventlistener does not work on iPhone

Tags: javascript, ios, mobile, safari

I have several events that use keyup, but they do not fire on iOS in safari. Is there another event listener that can accomplish similar actions?

Example of keyup I use to detect when someone is typing in a searchbox

```
document.getElementById('user_search_select').addEventListener("keyup", e=>{livebox(usersearch_counter=0)});
```

Comment: Try "input" instead of "keyup"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer here: `document.getElementById('user_search_select').addEventListener("input", e=>{livebox(usersearch_counter=0)});`